# Devexpress radio button list items change colour

Tags: devexpress-mvc

I am trying to disable the radio button button list based on user selection. When the radio button list is disabled how can i change the list items text color?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

used below code in CSS

```
 label.dxeRadioButtonList_MetropolisBlue, .dxeDisabled_MetropolisBlue .dxichTextCellSys .dx-wrap {
    color: #CCCCCC !important;
}
```